# Logistic Inference Question

Tags: r, logistic, inference, regression-coefficients

```
mlbench::data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

PimaIndiansDiabetes$glucose = na_if(PimaIndiansDiabetes$glucose, 0)
PimaIndiansDiabetes$insulin = na_if(PimaIndiansDiabetes$insulin, 0)
PimaIndiansDiabetes$mass= na_if(PimaIndiansDiabetes$mass, 0)
PimaIndiansDiabetes$triceps= na_if(PimaIndiansDiabetes$triceps, 0)
PimaIndiansDiabetes$pressure= na_if(PimaIndiansDiabetes$pressure, 0)

pima <- PimaIndiansDiabetes

PositiveTest <- pima[pima$test == 1,]
NegativeTest <- pima[pima$test == 0,]

PosMod <- glm(test~., PositiveTest, family = "binomial")
NegMod <- glm(test~., NegativeTest, family = "binomial")

coefficients(PosMod)["diastolic"]
coefficients(NegMod)["diastolic"]

##     diastolic 
## -2.805163e-16

##    diastolic 
## 2.916048e-16
```

> Based off the coefficients, those who tested negative have a lower chance of having high diastolic pressure.

This was the answer for an assignment in class last year. I'm reviewing but simply don't understand how the coefficients are being interpreted to arrive the quote written above.

Thank You.

Comment: With the exponent being $-16$, the coefficient is so small that I have trouble taking it seriously. That is basically the way R tells you the number is zero. // In order for someone to answer, it would be helpful if you explained what your code does.

Comment: The R code in your question will give nonsense results. First, your `glm` calls are not syntactically correct. Perhaps you meant `glm(test~., data=PositiveTest, family = "binomial")`, but that would still be nonsense because you would be doing two fits, one with only positive cases and one with only negative cases. Both fits will simply give infinite intercept and all other coefficients equal to zero.

Comment: @Dave I have no clue. This was the answer key for analyzing the pima dataset

Comment: @Antonio That code does not even compile for me: “Error: 'data' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mlbench'”. Is there more to the posted solution? // Even if there is, I have trouble taking seriously such a small number.

Comment: @Dave I updated the code.

Comment: @Antonio The code still does not compile; the data set does not load.